# Dockerode Equivalent of Command

Tags: javascript, docker, express, dockerode

I'm looking to use dockerode to run a function in nodejs that is the equivalent to the following command line command:

`docker run --rm -v ${filename}:/docker.py image-name`

I am unsure about how to do this (especially how to use flags like --rm and -v).

Thank you!